# Drupal core tries to update to current version

Tags: updating

Many sites on my server are running Drupal 7.23, I usually use Drush to update them without any issue. Eveything works fine with modules and themes but Core keeps installing 7.23 on itself.

The *admin/reports/updates* page display this :

[image]

```
Drupal Core 7.23
  Recommended version: 7.23
  Security update: 7.24
  Last version: 7.25
```

It obviously tries to update to the recommended version, which is in this case the current one (7.23).

I use the permissions guidelines given in the script on the bottom of [this page](https://drupal.org/node/244924). I tried to change the file owner, it is not working. We recently installed Nginx as a reverse proxy on our server but the problem still the same calling directly Apache.

I also have some sites running Drupal 7.24 and no issue when updating to 7.25.

Any clue on the origin of this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, with the following command line.

```
drush pm-update drupal-7.25
```

I still do not understand why the regular update fails but this last command works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any installation with 7.23, but would you try to do first a security-only update:

```
drush pm-update --security-only
```

Maybe that would do the trick that it updates to 7.24, which is a security update. Then you can update it again to 7.25 in a regular way.

As I said, I didn't test it, but it worths to try.

Comment: after drush pm-update --security-only same: Name Installed Version Proposed version Message Drupal 7.23 7.23 SECURITY UPDATE available

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a drupal.org updatexml bug. A regression in https://drupal.org/node/2167845#comment-8370565. Also reported at https://drupal.org/node/2167845#comment-8370565